# How to read two days value from DB with PHP

Tags: php

I want to write a code to generate 2 days result from DB.e.g, if today is wednesdy, it should read Monday and Tuesday on WEDNESDAY...:same process continue like that i have tried several methods i seems not to get it right. am relatively new with php. This is  my code:

```
$today = date("format",time());
$this->today= ('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$this->startdate    = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($today .' -2 day'));

$this->enddate      = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($today .' -1 day'));

   //then i call the function

$this->calcMonitoringDate();
```

this was my output:

```
string 'f2017Mon, 20 Nov 2017 15:33:57 +010011pm30 -1 day'
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. No one here has any idea what your `calcMonitoringDate` method does.

Comment: its a function()

Comment: public function calcMonitoringDate()

Comment: am working on already existing framework. .. i want to add the above mentioned functionality..

Comment: _"am working on already existing framework"_ - and still no one here besides you knows which one that is ...

Comment: @TONY there is a lot more information you need to provide for anyone to help you. Do you have any code written for `calcMonitoringDate()`? If so please post. If not you need to clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish, in a lot more detail. What framework are you using?

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem. Sorry for my late response i was away for some weeks..

Answer (score 0):

You may do some thing like this

> select * from table  where
>   str_to_date(end_date, '%d/%m/%Y') < date_sub(curdate(),interval 2 day);

Date_sub is function get 2 days old date,